# A word for people who resist change

Tags: etymology

I'm new to the site. So, be nice. I googled the question earlier because I forgot the word I was going to use to decribe a friend of mine. The question and (lack of) answers were from 2013. I found the answer elsewhere and decided to come back to join in this site. 
Luddite is the answer to the question I was asking, although that is generally geared toward resistance to technical change. The etymology on this word is fun to know.

Comment: ***Luddite (n.) :*** 
also luddite, 1811, ***from name taken by an organized band of weavers who destroyed machinery in Midlands and northern England 1811-16 for fear it would deprive them of work.***  Supposedly from Ned Ludd, a Leicestershire worker who in 1779 had done the same before through insanity (but that story first was told in 1847). Applied to modern rejecters of automation and technology from at least 1961. As an adjective from 1812. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=luddite+

Comment: I can't see the question here.

Comment: I answered my own question and then shared it. Also open to synonymous words. Conservative is good although I typically use conservative as an adjective in the inasmuch as marked by moderation or caution. Or political conviction. I live where negative connotation toward conservatives wouldn't get me too far. Although it is the description in the dictionary ahead of mine. Thank you. I'll try to not be vague in the future. Luddite was the word in question.

Comment: Hi @A.Burton, and welcome to the site!  Self-answering a question is a good thing (it's always nice to share your knowledge).  The preferred way to go about it is to post only your question in the Question box, and then post your answer in the Answer box.  As you've got it right now, you have the answer in the question box.  Would you be willing / able to split it up?

Answer (score 1):

To describe a person "reluctant to change", you may use **[conservative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conservative?s=t)** that is both an adjective and a noun.

> adjective definition: disposed to preserve existing conditions, institutions, etc., or to restore traditional ones, and to limit change; traditional in style or manner; avoiding novelty or showiness.
>
> noun definition: a person who is conservative in principles, actions,
> habits, etc; *also a supporter of conservative political policies*.

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: I added [Dictionary.com] to your post.

Comment: Thanks. Look up Luddite then look it up in thesaurus and you'll find no synonyms nor is it available in thesaurus. Your help is appreciated but as mentioned it's been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers already given, [stick-in-the-mud](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick-in-the-mud) can describe somebody who may be, among other things, resistant to change.

> noun \ˈstik-ən-thə-ˌməd\
>
> someone who has old-fashioned ideas or who does not like trying new or exciting things

Comment: Luddite is the word I was looking for. Stick-in-the-mud does no justice to the person I was describing. There is some more colorful language that may.